# How to change date format to 24 hours format in prime ng schedule

Tags: angular, schedule, primeng

In my angular2 application, I am trying to change the time format (displaying via prime Ng schedule) to 24 hours format.

Ex - Right now its displaying like 1AM, 2AM... but I want it like 13AM, 14AM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to change manually using javascript according to me

Answer (score 0):

Use the showTime input property

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" showTime="showTime" hourFormat="24"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: questioner is  talking about `p-schedule` not about `p-calendar`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it didn't work for me. Right @Pradeep, its about p-schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for this.
To install moment:

```
npm install moment --save
```

Next, you can use it in any .ts file after importing it:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
```